# Pandas sum every other column by index where names, and index size changes

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Here is my current dataframe named out

```
Date    David_Added David_Removed   Malik_Added Malik_Removed   Meghan_Added    Meghan_Removed  Sucely_Added    Sucely_Removed
02/19/2019  3   1   39  41  1   6   14  24
02/18/2019  0   0   8   6   0   3   0   0
02/16/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/15/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/14/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/13/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/12/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/11/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/08/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02/07/2019  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I need to sum every persons data by date obviously skipping the Date column. I would like the total to be the column next to the columns summed. "User_Add, User_Removed, User_Total" as shown below. My issue I face is that the prefix names won't always be the same, and the total amount of users changes.
My thought process would be count the total columns. Then loop through them doing the math, and dumping the results to a new column for every user. Then sort the columns alphabetically so they are grouped together.

something along the line of

```
loops = out.shape[1]
while loop < loops:
    out['User_Total'] = out['User_Added']+out['User_Removed']
    loop += 1
out.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However I'm not sure how to call an entire column by index, or if this is even a good way to handle it.

Here is what I'd like the output to look like.

```
Date    David_Added David_Removed   David_Total Malik_Added Malik_Removed   Malik_Total Meghan_Added    Meghan_Removed  Meghan_Total    Sucely_Added    Sucely_Removed  Sucely_Total
2/19/2019   3   1   4   39  41  80  1   6   7   14  24  38
2/18/2019   0   0   0   8   6   14  0   3   3   0   0   0
2/16/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/15/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/14/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/13/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/12/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/11/2019   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/8/2019    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/7/2019    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` with columns `split`

```
s=df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1).sum().drop('Date',1).add_suffix('_Total')
yourdf=pd.concat([df,s],1).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
yourdf
Out[455]: 
         Date  David_Added      ...       Sucely_Removed  Sucely_Total
0  02/19/2019            3      ...                   24            38
1  02/18/2019            0      ...                    0             0
2  02/16/2019            0      ...                    0             0
3  02/15/2019            0      ...                    0             0
4  02/14/2019            0      ...                    0             0
5  02/13/2019            0      ...                    0             0
6  02/12/2019            0      ...                    0             0
7  02/11/2019            0      ...                    0             0
8  02/08/2019            0      ...                    0             0
9  02/07/2019            0      ...                    0             0
[10 rows x 13 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
df.join(df.T.groupby(df.T.index.str.split("_").str[0]).sum().T.iloc[:,1:].add_suffix('_Total'))

        Date  David_Added  David_Removed  Malik_Added  Malik_Removed  \
0  02/19/2019            3              1           39             41   
1  02/18/2019            0              0            8              6   
2  02/16/2019            0              0            0              0   
3  02/15/2019            0              0            0              0   
4  02/14/2019            0              0            0              0   
5  02/13/2019            0              0            0              0   
6  02/12/2019            0              0            0              0   
7  02/11/2019            0              0            0              0   
8  02/08/2019            0              0            0              0   
9  02/07/2019            0              0            0              0   

   Meghan_Added  Meghan_Removed  Sucely_Added  Sucely_Removed David_Total  \
0             1               6            14              24           4   
1             0               3             0               0           0   
2             0               0             0               0           0   
3             0               0             0               0           0   
4             0               0             0               0           0   
5             0               0             0               0           0   
6             0               0             0               0           0   
7             0               0             0               0           0   
8             0               0             0               0           0   
9             0               0             0               0           0   

  Malik_Total Meghan_Total Sucely_Total  
0          80            7           38  
1          14            3            0  
2           0            0            0  
3           0            0            0  
4           0            0            0  
5           0            0            0  
6           0            0            0  
7           0            0            0  
8           0            0            0  
9           0            0            0
```

Comment: Looks like it didn't work because my mistake. Didn't realise I imported the CSV as a  string. This also worked after making that change.

Comment: Glad to know that. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm aware my this is not an answer for the question the OP posed, it is an advice on better practices that would solve the problem he is facing.

You have a structural problem. Having your dataframe modeled as such:

```
Date User_Name User_Added User_Removed User_Total
```

would make the code you've entered the solution to your problem, besides handling the variable number of users.